# How to be sure in Laravel to not twice load scripts and adding version of app to them

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I working with Laravel right now and maybe You will help me to find a solution for my problem. I need to be sure not to load again scripts which are already loaded.
When I trying to generate a view, sometimes I am including a lot of components. For exemple DataTables because I need to display on page three or more tables. So it is very hard to check if some of scripts arent doubled or tripled or even more...

I also would like to adding a version of app to URL, somethign like this:
`<script src="{{url('/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=1.0.1')}}"></script>`
but I would like to getting this **ver** from somewhere in app like in config maybe. So result should be: when I change ver of app it is changing globally in or URLs so the web browser will fresh load those scripts.
Whats more I would like to adding this **?ver=verOfApp** automaticly to all scripts. I am not sure how to do it. Maybe make own helper in *app/helpers.php*.

Thanks for a help!

Comment: Compile all scripts together and just load one.

Comment: What You mean? How to do that?

Comment: Obviously [reading the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix) is your first step.

Comment: I think You are right, thanks m8!